# DialogFragment with RecyclerView slower than Fragment with Recyclerview

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-dialogfragment

I wonder why my **DialogFragment** (with  a **RecyclerView** inside) takes much longer to show on my debugging device than when i start a new Fragment with the same Layout as it is in the **DialogFragment**.

The bigger my **List** (for the adapter) with **Objects** is, the bigger is the time difference.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem - I have a listview embedded in a dialogFragment with nested imageViews / textviews within each rowView.

My suspicion is that the dialogFragment is never designed to display large listviews and the recycler isn't quite optimised for this use case.

What I ended up doing is to launch an activity via an explicit intent and with that the performance issues seems to have gone away, in the sense that whatever the size of the listview (I have tested between 1-20 rows, so not the most extensive testing...) the load time is roughly the same.

I know this doesn't exactly answering your question but thought I'd share my experience as I have had to deal with the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your idea! I solved it with embedding an horizontal recyclerView inside the Fragment - which displayed the content -> then there wasnt the need for me to use a DialogFragment anymore :)

Comment: Same issue, :(

I am building an medical management system app, Where I am opening a DialogFragment and using a recyclerview to view the products.
on click of product we are calling some API.etc

how can I fix the lag or slow working app.

any suggestion please. @Jimmy